# An issue with jQuery countdown

Tags: jquery, html

After a few hours of searching I found a solution to my problem but I still have one problem.  I am  using the http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ on my site to make a countdown.

This is what I am using:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5by8xcwp/3/)

```
 $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
   })
 .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
   $(this).html('expired!');

 });
  });
```

That works great, it shows an expired txt as I like it to be but if I reload the page the expire disappears and 00:00:00 shows.  Is any way to keep the expired text even after reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the below JS to your existing code in **`each`** loop.

```
if ($(this).text() == '00:00:00') $(this).html('expired!');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gc0ukgr/)

This `finish.countdown` event is fired only when timer expires after starting, but your timer is already expired in page load, so **this event will not fire**. so simply use a `if` condition to check the text and replace it.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is mich simpler than using localstorage

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is run on page load, when you refresh the page it would have no idea that it's been run before. To keep it at 00:00:00 when you refresh you'd need to store the information either client side using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) or send a request to your server to save the information into a database, then once you reload get the info from the database and if it's already hit 00:00:00 according to your database then show it.

Comment: Some code would be helpful here. What should he put in `'finish.countdown'` event in case he wants to use `localstorage`?

Comment: The if I use localstorage will be something like this right http://jsfiddle.net/5by8xcwp/5/  but can't make it change

Comment: When your page loads check it it's set as expired and then don't run the countdown. If it's not set then run it.